# php dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to store  key of $array into $newarray as its key
but it gives undefined index A , D

```
   $newarray = array();

  $array = array('A'=>'b', 'D'=>'ewe'); 
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 
     $newarray[$key] .= 'data';
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want but,

```
$newarray[$key] .= 'data';
```

must be

```
$newarray[$key] = 'data'; // without the "."!
```

Comment: thank, didn't see the dot

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 
     $newarray[$key] = 'data';  //Remove .
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating to a value that doesn't already exist. Assign to it instead.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 
    $newarray[$key] = 'data';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..............sorry i though of another thing please remove negative

```
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 
    $newarray[$key] = 'data';
  }
```